# Images that has been deleted from database,be deleted from storage,too

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")

class Image(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')

class Tour(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   PriceUnit=models.ForeignKey(PriceUnit)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   Gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery,editable=False)
```

as U can see each tour has a gallery of images,I've designed a ModelForm that let user add a tour,this is it's code in views.py:

```
def addtour(request,key):
   ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Gallery,Image, can_delete=False,extra=4)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      gform=GalleryForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
      if gform.is_valid():
         gallery=gform.save(commit=False)
         formset=ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=gallery)
      if formset.is_valid():
         gallery.save()
         formset.save()
      tform = TourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if tform.is_valid():
         tour=tform.save(commit=False)
         tour.ActionUserCode=User.objects.get(pk=1)
         tour.Gallery=gallery
         tour.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('airAgency.views.edittour', args=[agn.WebSite,tour.pk]))#'airAgency/edittour/%i/' % (tour.pk))
   else:
      tform = TourForm()
      gform=GalleryForm()
      galleryinstance=Gallery()
      formset=ImageFormSet(instance=galleryinstance)
   return render_to_response('airAgency/addtour.html', {'tform': tform,'gform':gform,'formset':formset})
```

as U can see in views,after adding a tour,user is redirected to edittour page.now I wanna when user in edittour page delete a tour or when Images belong to it's Gallery is deleted ,Images be deleteed from storage in addition to deleting from database.how can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the delete() method on a model to do what you want.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

```
class Image:
    #other code is here

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #code to remove from file system goes here
        super(Image, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: so,how can I delete related images from storage while deleting them from database,in overrided save() method?

Comment: Not sure why you didn't just google it, but http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove

Comment: Also, I modified my answer so that it overrides the delete() method, rather than save.

Comment: documentation U suggest is for python,I'm new in django and I don't know how should I write such code to delete Images.how can I get path of these images and how can I delete them from that path?

Comment: Are you doing some sort of custom storage (if you don't know, then the answer is no)? Because the FileField and ImageField automatically take care of all of the storage and deletion for you by Django, and hence this entire question is not necessary.

Comment: but when I remove a record that have Image,it's Images doesn't delete automatically!!